# Best way to "emulate" a FloatingActionButton on Android? (Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

As of today, there's no native support for FloatingActionButton on Appcelerator Titanium yet, so I was wondering which is the best way to emulate it.

I want to create a FloatingActionButton like this one:
[image: Correct FloatingActionButton]

I tried different approaches but none of them seem to be 100% accurate.

I've seen that there's a couple of modules on GitHub, but one of them does not accept icons or at least I don't know how to use them (https://github.com/k0sukey/be.k0suke.tifab) and the other one requires me to enable Hyperloop and disable LiveView (https://github.com/appcelerator-forks/loop-modules.Ti.FAB), which will slow down compilation times and thus making me waste a lot of time.

I also tried creating a circular view with an ImageView inside it, but it's not showing correctly, the backgroundColor is not covering all the View:

[image: Wrong FloatingActionButton]

My code looks like this:

XML:

```
<View id="locateView">
    <ImageView id="locateUser" touchEnabled="false" />
</View>
```

JS:

```
// This is half of 32dp
Alloy.Globals.borderRadiusFAB = ( parseInt("32dp") * (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.dpi / 160));
```

TSS:

```
"#locateView" : {
    bottom: "12dp",
    right: "12dp",
    height: "48dp",
    width: "48dp",
    borderRadius : Alloy.Globals.borderRadiusFAB,
    backgroundColor: '#80FFFFFF',
    touchFeedback: true,
    touchFeedbackColor: "#808080",
    elevation: 10
}

"#locateUser" : {
    height: "32dp",
    width: "32dp",
    image : "/icons/my_location.png"
}
```

I am using Titanium SDK 6.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only issue is in using the ImageView which seems to have some background color. There are multiple ways to create this button, but here is a sample app which creates almost 99% similar FAB button.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4ZdsEjK2ySIMXd1YS15ZTk1TDg/view?usp=sharing

It contains a sample source code of how you can create better FAB buttons for iOS & Android using single code-base. It also contains a Material Font file which shows how you can use Fonts to create vector image/icons instead of ImageView.

Here's the link to read more about using **Labels** in places of **ImageView**.

https://medium.com/all-titanium/cool-technique-to-use-vector-icons-using-iconic-font-files-aab4513aa8da

This sample code will create icons like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your solution works, but I tried adding transparency to the backgroundColor of the ".floating-btn" and I still have the same problem that it does not fill the whole View: https://i.imgur.com/t0MflnM.png

Could it be an Appcelerator bug?

Comment: I have never tried setting transparency with touchFeedback since the docs Appc says that **Touch feedback is applied only if the backgroundColor is a solid color.**

Comment: @PrashantSaini I’ve tried your solution, but it doesn’t seem to have the usual floating action button ripple effect on Android. How would I enable this? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you cannot see touch-feedback effect if your same view's background color is transparent. Simply say, the feedback color transparency is direct related to bg color. Secondly, you have to make sure that the view having feedback color should be able to receive touch-events and its childs should have touchEnabled set to false. Better if you can share your simple XML and tss codes so we can assist faster.